# How Do I Uses Pythagoras In Python?

Tags: python, pygame, pythagorean

How do you write the Pythagoras equation in python? Is it written as shown below or not. If not please describe why this is incorrect and how I can correct it.

`math.sqrt(XLength^2+YLength^2)`

Comment: Why do you use `int()`?

Comment: Python exponential operator is **, not ^

Comment: no; `^` is [bitwise XOR](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), while you want `**` for exponentiation!

Comment: Thanks, just taken int() out and it still 'works' but is the rest of it OK?

Comment: Thanks unlut and ti7 just replaced the ^ with ** and it worked a charm, I am new to python and have been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: I didn't ignore your answer I responded to yours first and thanks for the `math.hypot(XLength, YLength)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pygame you can use [`pygame.math.Vector2.length`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.length):

```py
l = pygame.math.Vector2(XLength, YLength).length()
```

In general you can use [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html):

```py
l = math.hypot(XLength, YLength)
```

`^` however is the Bitwise Exclusive Or operator (see [opertor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator)). The Exponentiation operator is `**`:

```py
l = math.sqrt(XLength**2 + YLength**2)
```